# Command to delete files except those beginning with a prefix from another directory

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

Let's say I am currently in c:\test\user, but I need to delete certain files in a different directory, say C:\testb\data\diff.  The files I need to delete are those that DO NOT begin with AD_.  Is it possible to do this in one command line statement?

Answer (score 1):

> **MS DOS command delete files except those beginning with a prefix from another directory**
>
> The files I need to delete are those that DO NOT begin with AD_. Is it
>   possible to do this in one command line statement?

**Command line to delete from a specific folder except for a particular file name pattern**

Just run the below statement from command line with a copy and paste. This uses [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop with a [**DIR**](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) piped to a [**FINDSTR**](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) command of what pattern to match for the exclusion.

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %A IN ('DIR /A-D /B "C:\testb\data\diff" ^| FINDSTR /I /V "AD_"') DO DEL /Q /F "C:\testb\data\diff\%~A"
```

If you want to explicitly set your directory to delete from variable as well as the file pattern to exclude, below is an example with doing it this way.

```
SET DelDir=C:\testb\data\diff
SET DelPattern=AD_

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %A IN ('DIR /A-D /B "%DelDir%" ^| FINDSTR /I /V "%DelPattern%"') DO DEL /Q /F "%DelDir%\%~A"
```